# Como fazer para preencher dados de endereço através do CNPJ?

Tags: javascript

Estou montando um cadastro de cliente via Web e gostaria de saber se é possível preencher, automaticamente, os dados do endereço através do preenchimento do campo CNPJ?

Comment: Existe a [receitaws](https://www.receitaws.com.br/api), que traz os dados em JSON, por exemplo o [CNPJ da Petrobras](https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/33000167000101)

Comment: Obrigado.. é isso que eu preciso !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar pesquisar o CNPJ no [site da receita federal](http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/Cnpjreva_Solicitacao2.asp).

#### Processo

- Usar algum serviço de *curl* ou *soap* via servidor para simular um cliente e recuperar as informações.
- Usar um parser de HTML para recuperar os dados desejados.

#### Problemas

- Possui captcha, mas pelos meus testes só a necessidade de preencher uma vez, apos isso basta consultar normalmente.
- Possui um *timer* de sessão para o captcha de + ou - 5min.

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço nenhuma framework que possa trazer esta informação de "bandeja" para você, creio que não exista.

Será necessário um serviço de banco de dados, na qual haverão no mínimo os campos cnpj (primary key), endereço, cep, etc.

Para desenvolvimento, pode utilizar o mySql com o xampp ou com o wampServer. =)

Answer (score 0):

Existe algumas empresas que disponibilizam como esta:

http://www.soawebservices.com.br/departamentos/cdc/default.aspx

Mas é feita uma cobrança por consulta.